# Accessing argument's metadata in Clojure macro

Tags: clojure, macros

Is there a way to retrieve the metadata of the arguments inside a clojure macro without using `eval`? The only thing I could come up with so far is this:

```
(def ^{:a :b} my-var)

(defmacro my-macro [s] (prn (eval `(meta (var ~s)))))

(my-macro my-var)
;; Prints {:a :b, :name my-var, ...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution:

```
(def ^{:a :b} my-var)

(defmacro my-macro [s] (prn (meta (resolve s))))

(my-macro my-var)
;; Prints {:a :b, :name my-var, ...}
```

So the key part here is to use `resolve` function to get the var associated to the symbol.