# Clojure: Take a macro metadata inside another macro

Tags: clojure, macros

On one of my pet projects I have a bunch of macros, and sometimes I want to be able to read metadata from macro definition. The reason being that sometimes my other macros should expand differently depending on input form. Of course, it is rather simpler to just expand and then read metadata, but I wonder if it's possible to do while macro is expanding.

Consider following macro:

```clj
(defmacro stackoverflow 
  {:example 23} 
  [& args] 
  (comment "This is just an example"))
```

It is perfectly simple to read metadata from macro in regular function.

```clj
(defn- -example?
  [form-var]
  (-> form-var
      meta
      :example
      some?))

:=> (-example? #'stackoverflow)
true
```

It is not hard to do inside another macro as well:

```clj
(defmacro example?-macro[form] 
  `(-example? (var ~form)))

:=> (example?-macro stackoverflow)
true
```

But I couldn't find a way to get meta while macro is expanding:

```clj
(defmacro test-example? [form]
  (if (example?-macro form)
    (println "It is indeed an example")
    (println "It is not and example!")))

> Unable to resolve var: form in this context
```

I want my `test-example?` to do different job depending on the input form, but couldn't find a way to do it.

**In short the whole question boils to: How to take var from input macro inside macro without expanding like so:**

```clj
;; This is desired behaviour

(defmacro imagining-solution
  [form]
  (if (:example `(meta (var ~form)))
    (println "It is indeed an example")
    (println "It is not and example!")))

;; But one can only dream about
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after posting this question ;) found a solution here:
[Accessing argument's metadata in Clojure macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679637/accessing-arguments-metadata-in-clojure-macro?rq=2)

Just use `resolve` function!

Comment: This doesn't really address shadowing. For example, someone may write `(let [stackoverflow false] (example?-macro stackoverflow))`. You will resolve `#'stackoverflow` to its var and conclude it is a macro, but if you had just expanded normally, you would have found it's a local variable that evaluates to false.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Is there a way to address shadowing? Even though I don't need it for my task, still I'm curious, is there a way r not.

Comment: You can look in `&env` to see if there's a local shadowing it. I think that should cover every case? But of course it's much nicer to just not expand differently based on whether there's a macro inside. It's a pretty rare thing to want; I don't remember ever seeing it before.

Comment: It would be nicer, of course and much more simpler. What I'm trying to do is: I have a several macro, that change the order of arguments for given function. Like switch places for first and second, or last or any other. I had such functions, and one day I've decided to write macros having same functionality. Reasoning being just for fun, hacking and deepen my knowledge. With such macros arise the need in substitution of -> and ->> since they will fail. New macros for threading use a meta to decide wether expand the form first, before providing an argument or not.